# Web service on Play framework not accepting POST message

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am sending the following message from an Angular Service to a play application

```
  public createUser(user:User):any{
    console.log('contacting server at '+this.API_URL +this.ADD_USER_URL +" with user data ",user);
    /*http.post returns an observable. The caller's code should subscribe to this observable */
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL +this.ADD_USER_URL,user)
      .map(response => { //handler if post's Observable is successful. map creates new User and returns Observable<User>.
        console.log('response from backend service',response);
        //return new User(response); //the constructor of User allows passing an object.
        /*when the observable of http.post returns (produces) data (the response), the map function prints a message and returns that response*/
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError); //error handler if Observable fails
  }
```

I am getting the following warning on Play's console and forbidden response.
`[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because application/json for request /ws/users/add`

```
WebToBackendInterfaceService::handleError 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden", url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/users/add", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:9000/ws/users/add: 403 Forbidden", error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n    <head>\n        <title>Unauthorized</title>\n        <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"data:image/png;base64,...">\n        <style>\n            html, body, pre {\n                margin: 0;\n                padding: 0;\n                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;\n                background: #ECECEC;\n            }\n            h1 {\n                margin: 0;\n                background: #333;\n                padding: 20px 45px;\n                color: #fff;\n                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);\n                border-bottom: 1px solid #111;\n                font-size: 28px;\n            }\n            p#detail {\n                margin: 0;\n                padding: 15px 45px;\n                background: #888;\n                border-top: 4px solid #666;\n                color: #111;\n                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);\n                font-size: 14px;\n                border-bottom: 1px solid #333;\n            }\n        </style>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Unauthorized</h1>\n\n        <p id=\"detail\">\n            You must be authenticated to access this page.\n        </p>\n\n    </body>\n</html>\n" }
```

It seems that Play's CSRF doesn't like this message. How could I solve the issue? I read that in Play, the error happens when

1. Request is not GET, HEAD or Option - true in my case, I am sending a POST message
2. Request has cookie or Authorisation header. I am not sending them explicitly. Does Angular sends it by default?
3. The CORS filter is not configured to trust  request's origin. - I am sending request to localhost:9000. Shouldn't Play trust localhost?

How could I make Play accept my message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a workaround. Correct explanation is in [Angular not sending CSRF token in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243862/angular-not-sending-csrf-token-in-header). Basically, my client should send a CSRF Header with token initially created by the play framework

I do not know if this is the correct way but I had to disable CSRF in Play. It could be done in the following two ways

In `routes` file, add `nocsrf` above the rule

```
+nocsrf
POST /ws/users/add                  controllers.UserController.addUser
```

Or disable csrf completely in `application.conf`

```
play.filters {


  # Disabled filters remove elements from the enabled list.
  disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
}
```

I disabled `csrf` completely

Comment: Disabling CSRF is a bad idea for security. You should follow the answer below and add the proper token to your header on the request.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you set up your frontend HTTP client with header and cookie names ["Csrf-Token"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCsrf#Plays-CSRF-protection). I had the same issue with my Angular+Play seed, turns out Angular's [defaults cookie and header names](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-custom-cookieheader-names) for CSRF are XSRF-TOKEN and X-XSRF-TOKEN. So in my case I had to import another Angular module to override those values:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'Csrf-Token',
      headerName: 'Csrf-Token',
    }),
    routing
  ]
```

Although disabling Play's CSRF protection(based on Manu Chadha's answer) might be a workaround but it is strongly advised against.

Comment: This really should be listed as the correct answer. Disabling CSRF is easy, but is not the long-term solution. I will note that the name 'Csrf-Token' is essential. If you web search for CSRF you will find various names for this. That string is what Play is expecting and others won't work.

I'm currently writing code using React (through Slinky) on the client-side and using fetch for Ajax calls. In my main view, I have `@import views.html.helper.CSRF` and add `data-token='@CSRF.getToken.value'` to the body. Then in the fetch header, I get the data-token and add it under the key 'Csrf-Token'.